# How should I price sale or license of my photographs to a site which will sell them in turn?

Tags: pricing, licensing

I have a celebrity charity event coming up soon. I am photographing VIPs at step & repeat with four celebrities, stage show with 20+ celebrities, VIP party with all celebrities. This is a 5 hour event, and with sales on my site I can make some good money.

I just found out the benefactor of this charity event (which is a hospital) wants full rights to my images (freelancer/I own copyright) because they want to sell them on their foundation's website.

I decided to take a look at this website and found out that the celebrity VIP photos I shot (at no cost) in  2013 are for sale stating **'photos by bla bla hospital'**. I understand I can sue for copyright infringement. At the moment I am more concerned with how much to charge for (buy-out licensing) or (non exclusive shared licensing) of the event images (usually around 400-500) for the upcoming celeb charity event. Oh... they are selling my images as digital downloads for far less than they are on my site!!!

If this hospital does not want to pay my licensing price, then I will start working on the 2013 images lawsuit. First I would just like some input on the buy-out licensing giving them the right to sell my digital images as downloads, shared rights, most likely giving them lo res images.

Comment: Hi! This question would render answers that would be based on opinion to a large degree. This site is not well suited for that and legal advice is also outside the scope of the site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to price my photos to be used on someone else's website?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45858/how-to-price-my-photos-to-be-used-on-someone-elses-website)

Comment: I don't think this is the same as pricing to be used on a website. It's priced for someone else to sell.

Comment: That said, I think what you need to do is talk to a lawyer. Is this a for-profit hospital?

Comment: This would also be very dependant on any contracts signed. Your best to consult a legal professional about how to approach the copyright infringement.